# Python - Return value from Column B every time Column A equals 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'd like to return the value of Column B every time Column A equals 0. My current code:

```
for i in df:
    checkfornulls = df.ix[(df['A'][i] == 0).idxmin(),'B']
    if checkfornulls is None:
        print "Column A Pass!"
    else:
        print checkfornulls
```

if i just run this on it's own:

```
checkfornulls = df.ix[(df['A'][i] == 0).idxmin(),'B']
    if checkfornulls is None:
        print "Column A Pass!"
    else:
        print checkfornulls
```

then it brings back the first 0 it finds. Does anyone know how to make the for loop work so that it brings back every instance that A equals 0?

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` provides a great number of ways to accomplish this task.  It's quite a personal decision as to which is the best, most pythonic (whatever that means), or pandantic (another made up word).

using `query`
`df.query('A == 0').B`
or
`df.query('A == 0')['B']`

Comment: Won't option 2 here raise a setting on copy warning due to [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)?

Answer (score 2):

one way of doing it is

```
df[df['A']==0]['B']
```

Comment: this is a pandatonic (pythonic) answer.

Comment: This is [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and should not be encouraged, the returned data here will raise a warning if you attempt to modify it

Answer (score 2):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['A']==0, 'B']
```

Comment: This IMO is the most pandas-like method as this will return a view on the data and not a copy and won't raise a warning when modifying